# parent div class higher z-index than children

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wish to lay over a pattern indicating that an element is inactive.

```
li .inactive {
   background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAFUlEQVQImWNgQALTGgr+k8phYGAAAFSlChVXUdguAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat;
}
```

This is a transparent png with a cross pattern:  ///// so contents below can be semi-visible.

The problem is that since the children elements are within, they are not really covered by the background image; its just seems that they are covered. Its particularly ineffective on images with white areas.

So I tried using a higher z-index for a parent and lower for a child???

```
li .inactive {
     z-index: 9999;
}
li .inactive * {
     z-index: -1;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements (`position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`).

Comment: And please provide a fiddle the next time.

Comment: It is not possible to overlay a parent's background over its children - that is why background image is called a **background** image. However, you can create a pseudo element for the inactive class, assign it a background image such that it overlays the children.

Comment: oh. a pseduo-element. how amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

try setting your elements to `position:relative`, and then apply the `z-index`